UnsatisfiedDependencyException when starting spring boot application
I am learning Spring Boot and followed a tutorial on authentication. However, when I start the app, I encounter these errors:
2024-07-30T11:41:21.302+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] c.e.B.BoardGameHubApiApplication         : Starting BoardGameHubApiApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 12660 (C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes started by sszalai in C:\combit\BoardGameHub)
2024-07-30T11:41:21.305+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] c.e.B.BoardGameHubApiApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-30T11:41:21.783+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-30T11:41:21.832+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 42 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-07-30T11:41:22.554+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-07-30T11:41:22.563+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-30T11:41:22.563+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-07-30T11:41:22.610+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-30T11:41:22.610+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1253 ms
2024-07-30T11:41:22.723+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-30T11:41:22.773+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-07-30T11:41:22.817+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-30T11:41:23.093+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-30T11:41:23.122+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-30T11:41:23.389+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@15d58530
2024-07-30T11:41:23.391+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-30T11:41:23.427+02:00  WARN 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQL8Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-07-30T11:41:23.428+02:00  WARN 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2024-07-30T11:41:24.228+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-30T11:41:24.269+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-30T11:41:24.479+02:00 ERROR 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes\com\example\BoardGameHub\config\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in file [C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes\com\example\BoardGameHub\config\ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BoardGameHubApiApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Could not resolve attribute 'username' of 'com.example.BoardGameHub.model.User'
2024-07-30T11:41:24.500+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-07-30T11:41:24.502+02:00  WARN 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2024-07-30T11:41:24.502+02:00  WARN 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2024-07-30T11:41:24.504+02:00  WARN 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2024-07-30T11:41:24.504+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-30T11:41:24.505+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-07-30T11:41:24.512+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-07-30T11:41:24.519+02:00  INFO 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-30T11:41:24.533+02:00 ERROR 12660 --- [BoardGameHub - API] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at com.example.BoardGameHub.BoardGameHubApiApplication.main(BoardGameHubApiApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:147) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:516) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:222) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes\com\example\BoardGameHub\config\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in file [C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes\com\example\BoardGameHub\config\ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BoardGameHubApiApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Could not resolve attribute 'username' of 'com.example.BoardGameHub.model.User'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:266) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:240) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4414) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:128) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in file [C:\combit\BoardGameHub\target\classes\com\example\BoardGameHub\config\ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BoardGameHubApiApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.BoardGameHub.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String); Could not resolve attribute 'username' of 'com.example.BoardGameHub.model.User'
Factory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
...

Project Structure:
enter image description here
Application Config:
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> repository.findByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

JwtAuthenticationFilter:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        @NonNull
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        @NonNull
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    )
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                    new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}

Security Configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URL = {
        "/api/boardgames/**",
        "/api/boardgames",
        "/api/auth"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL)
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/users").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
                    .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ;

        return http.build();
    }
}

JwtService:
@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "89ff1b9b7d3ca6c4cd97f20eac18e825aeff2107d095ef41d0a3aca6d33ee172";

    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
            .parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(
        Map<String, Object> extractClaims,
        UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return Jwts
            .builder()
            .setClaims(extractClaims)
            .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
            .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
            .compact();
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails){
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(final String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(final String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
}

Authentication Service:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {
    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        var user = User.builder()
            .firstName(request.getFirstName())
            .lastName(request.getLastName())
            .userName(request.getUserName())
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
            .role(RoleEnum.USER)
            .build();

        repository.save(user);

        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder().token(jwtToken).build();
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                request.getUserName(),
                request.getPassword()
            )
        );
        var user = repository.findByUsername(request.getUserName())
            .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .token(jwtToken)
            .build();
    }
}

Authentication Controller:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService service;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
    }
}

I tried to identify the error, but since Spring Boot is entirely new to me, I didn't have much success. I have tried to add @EnableJpaRepositories on the App class.

Could not resolve attribute 'username' of 'com.example.BoardGameHub.model.User'. Please provide your User entity

Can you post the com.example.BoardGameHub.model.User source code? It seems that the field username can't be resolved (perhaps it is written as userName, or there is no getter / sette).

questions/suggestions should be posted as comments

Thank you so much for the help! That solved the problem. Have a nice day <3

@JAsgarov I know, and I'm sorry, but since my reputation is still low (under 50) I can't comment directly the main post.

oh i see:) noprobs

if it is not a typo and you allow an extra dependency there is Lombok there.

These types of issues occur very often, You just need to find out your Entity has proper annotation based on requirements.
Usually few annotations that every entity should have are the followings :
@StringBuilder @Entity @Table @Getter @Setter
Also you need ensure your dependencies are properly downloaded in pom file.
